# SQL: Return additional fields as columns grouped by SSN

Tags: sql, oracle

Our Oracle DB has people in it with a unique ID. If a person is entered multiple times there will be multiple rows with the same demographic information (SSN, Name, Address, etc) with a uniquely generated ID. What I need to do is take unique rows and pull out just the person ID(s) into columns on a single row.

Table Data:

```
Person ID | SSN | Name
----------------------
1234567890 | 123-12-1234 | John Doe
0987654321 | 123-12-1234 | John Doe
1234567891 | 126-16-1236 | Jim Doe
1234567892 | 126-16-1236 | Jim Doe
```

Desired Results:

```
Person ID | Person ID | SSN | Name
----------------------
1234567890 | 0987654321 | 123-12-1234 | John Doe
1234567891 | 1234567892 | 126-16-1236 | Jim Doe
```

I'm relatively new to SQL so if this is a really dumb/easy solution great!

Comment: What is the purpose of this exercise? Just to identify the duplicate id's? What are you going to do with this information? (That is: what are the next steps?) This question is important: depending on WHY you need to do this, the Desired Result may or may not be the optimal choice.

Comment: We must provide the unique person IDs in columns without duplicates to a 3rd party so ultimately they can merge 2 records to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you may have two, three, or perhaps more person id values for the same SSN - and you must find ALL the person id values in those cases. If you don't know how many different person id's may be linked to the same SSN, you won't know how many columns you need in the output (unless you know for sure there are AT MOST TWO person id's per SSN - but how would you know that?)

One way to get the data to the third party is to do something like

```
select   ssn, name, listagg(personid, ',') within group (order by personid) as id_list
from     t
group by ssn, name
having   count(*) > 1;
```

However, this may be better:

```
select   ssn, name, cnt, personid
from     ( select t.*, count(*) over (partition by ssn) as cnt
           from   t
         )
where    cnt > 1
order by ssn, personid;
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! This gets me close enough to what I needed to be usable. The only part I left out originally is there is a date field but it's in a different table and I was really trying to avoid doing a join.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems like a basic aggregation query:

```
select min(PersonID), max(PersonId), SSN, Name
from t
group by SSN, Name;
```

Note:  If you have more than two ids for a person, you will still only see the smallest and largest.

Comment: Perhaps add: `having min(personid) != max(personid)` to return just the bothersome rows.

Comment: So this worked for people with only 2 records, how would I accomplish the same thing for people with more than 2 records?